# how to do a 301 redirect for all urls in a subdirectory so that they redirect to the particular page but in the root

Tags: redirect

how to do a 301 redirect from domain.com/subdirectory/url.htm to domain.com/url.htm so that it redirects all the urls that were previously in the subdirectory but are now in the root directory. I have this

RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdirectory/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/

But it is redirecting all the pages that were in the subdirectory to the homepage and I want it to redirect to the matching url.

For example redirect
domain.com/subdirectory/blue.htm to domain.com/blue.htm

domain.com/subdirectory/yellow.htm to domain.com/yellow.htm

domain.com/subdirectory/red.htm to domain.com/red.htm

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

`R=301` causes the 301 redirect. `L` tells the parser to ignore any following rule. You can access the parts matched inside the parentheses by `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so forth.

Comment: thank you for your help, it's giving me a 404 error on the pages

Comment: @user2502936 Omit the leading slash. It went in there by accident.

Comment: thanks, still not working for me, it redirects to the root domain.com